# onNext and onComplete not called when using anonymous subscriber

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have the following code

```
Flux<String> myFlux=getFlux();
    documentIds
        .windowTimeout(WINDOW, Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .onBackpressureBuffer()
        .takeWhile(d -> !interrupted.get())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(processorThread))
        .buffer(bufferSize)
        subscribe(
            new Subscriber<>() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete() {
                System.out.println("complete");
              countDownLatch.countDown();
              }    
              @Override
              public void onError(Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("error");
                countDownLatch.countDown();
              }   
              @Override
              public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
                System.out.println("dd");
              }    
              @Override
              public void onNext(List<BaseEntity> entities) {
                System.out.println("next");
              }
            });
           countDownLatch.await();
```

Only the onSubscribe method is being called.
My program keep blocked on "countDownLatch.await();"

I have tried also using BaseSubscriber but same issue.
Here is a sample of the code I'm currently using.

```
documentIds
        .windowTimeout(WINDOW, Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .onBackpressureBuffer()
        .takeWhile(d -> !interrupted.get())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(processorThread))
        .buffer(bufferSize)
        subscribe(
            new BaseSubscriber<>() {
              @Override
              public void hookOnComplete() {
                System.out.println("complete");
                countDownLatch.countDown();
              }    
              @Override
              public void hookOnError(Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("error");
                countDownLatch.countDown();
              }  
              @Override
              public void hookOnSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
                System.out.println("dd");
              }   
              @Override
              public void hookOnNext(List<BaseEntity> entities) {
                System.out.println("next");
              }
            });
            countDownLatch.await();
```

But if I use the consumer method- I can consume my flus successfully.

```
documentIds
        .windowTimeout(WINDOW, Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .onBackpressureBuffer()
        .takeWhile(d -> !interrupted.get())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(processorThread))
        .buffer(bufferSize)
        subscribe(
            item -> {
              System.out.println("next");
            },
            error -> {
              System.out.println(error);
            },
            () -> {
              System.out.println("complete");
            });
```

Any explanation please about this behavior?

Comment: When providing a subscriber object, you are responsible for triggering requests from subscription. In the `onSubscribe(Subscription subscription)` method, you have to call `subscription.request(n)` with `n` the max number of items you want to consume before requesting more. This is descibed in [Subscriber api doc](https://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.3-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/Subscriber.html?is-external=true)